# Socket.io prepends '/#' to server ids

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm having a weird issue, I have just cloned a repo that was working perfectly fine, but for no aparent reason it isn't anymore.

Basically what's happening is that my socket.io server instance is prepending '/#' to the ids making them different from the client side.

So on the server side I have **/#zG3wncZxZvgRE7LKAAAA** and on the client side I have **zG3wncZxZvgRE7LKAAAA**

Also when the client is receiving a message, it's possible to see on the frames tab this:

```
4undefined
```

This is my app.js and `config.room = fabio1`:

```
import config from './config';
import io from './factories/io';

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.join('dmClient');
  socket.join(config.room);
  console.log('socketId', socket.id);
});
```

And this is my **/factories/io.js**

```
import socketIo from 'socket.io';
const io = socketIo(3000);

export default io;
```

This is not my front end but it also triggers the error:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Socket.IO Chat Example</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

      socket.on('connect', function () {
        console.log(socket.id);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

More info:

- socket.io - 1.4.5
- node - v4.4.0

Comment: Everything seems ok, maybe you should add client-side code here?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I added the front end but I don't think the problem is from that.

Comment: Try to remove `/factories/io.js` file, and inline all logic in app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Socket.io did some breaking changes with the 1.4.* version I have created this [issue](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2491) where [creole](https://github.com/creole) pointed out to these two issues [Default room name is not socket id](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2475) and [Server socket id doesn't match client's socket id](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2405)

So on the **server side** instead of using `socket.id` if we want the **client id** we need to use `socket.client.id`.

```
import config from './config';
import io from './factories/io';

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.join('dmClient');
  socket.join(config.room);
  console.log('socketId', socket.client.id);// this did the trick
});
```